# Debug CController class in Yii1 app with Xdebug

Tags: php, yii, xdebug

I have a Yii1 application and I am trying to debug the application with Xdebug.

The part that I want to debug is a controller action:

```
<?php

namespace Scrape\controllers;

use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsServices;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\AdWordsSessionBuilder;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\CampaignService;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\OrderBy;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Paging;
use Google\AdsApi\AdWords\v201809\cm\Selector;
use Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder;
use GuzzleHttp\Client;
use Scrape\domain\creator\IgnoreCreator;
use Scrape\domain\creator\MonitorCreator;
use Scrape\domain\creator\ProjectCreator;
use Scrape\domain\creator\TaskCreator;
use Scrape\domain\deleter\IgnoreDeleter;
use Scrape\domain\deleter\ProjectDeleter;
use Scrape\domain\deleter\ResultDeleter;
use Scrape\domain\deleter\TaskDeleter;
use Scrape\domain\Downloader;
use Scrape\domain\IgnoreFilter;
use Scrape\domain\repository\IgnoreRepository;
use Scrape\domain\repository\ProjectRepository;
use Scrape\domain\repository\ResultRepository;
use Scrape\domain\repository\TaskRepository;
use Scrape\domain\Google;
use Scrape\domain\TaskResetter;
use Scrape\domain\TaskSuggestionRetriever;
use Scrape\models\Ignore;
use Scrape\models\Monitor;
use Scrape\models\Project;
use Scrape\models\Query;
use Scrape\models\Result;
use Scrape\models\Task;
use Scrape\models\TaskIntention;
use Scrape\models\TaskKeywordForm;
use Scrape\models\TaskPopularity;
use Scrape\models\TaskStatus;
use User\models\UserType;
use function GuzzleHttp\Psr7\str;

class DefaultController extends \CController
{
      public function actionDownloadTask($id)
    {
       
        (new Downloader)->downloadByTask(TaskRepository::findOne($id));
    }

    public function actionDownloadProject($id)
    {
     
        (new Downloader)->downloadByProject(ProjectRepository::findOne($id));
    }   
}
```

But I get this error:

```
Exception has occurred.
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class "CController" not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\webScraper\protected\modules\scrape\controllers\DefaultController.php:44
Stack trace:
#0 {main}
  thrown
```

On the class definition.

So my question is: how to tackle this inconvenience?

This is my index.php file:

```
<?php
use application\components\WebApplication;

define('DIR_ROOT',getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR);

$autoload = DIR_ROOT . 'protected/vendor/autoload.php';
$config   = DIR_ROOT . 'protected/config/main.php';
$yii      = DIR_ROOT . 'protected/components/Yii.php';

// remove the following lines when in production mode
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// specify how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

require_once($autoload);
require_once($yii);

include DIR_ROOT . 'protected/components/WebApplication.php';

(new WebApplication($config))->run();
```

As you can see I have `$autoload` defined in the index.php file. Or do you mean something else?

Comment: 1. How is that related with xDebug? 2. Have you proper autoloader loaded?

Comment: What exactly do you mean with autoloader loaded?

Comment: Do you have autoloader call (Yii and/or composer) inside index.php file

Comment: Hi, I have autoload. see updated post

Comment: It's a typical error for the following situation. The error means that you are trying to debug your Controller file **directly** while bypassing the whole Yii framework bootstrap code hence no autoload is ever gets executed. You need to call your actual page URL (if it's a web page) instead: the request will go trough your `index.php` entry point script that will load class autoloading code and will route your request to the needed controller where your breakpoint should be hit. It's it's a CLI script then the same: you need to debug the actual command and not controller class directly.

Comment: @mightycodeNewton Is this error thrown accessing your application via normal URL call or via some other way? If via `yiic`, then autoloader must be called in `yiic.php` too As @lazyOne told, error indicates that your class is not loaded via autoloader, either autoloader not called or it not able to locate class. Try step-debugging your autoloader via xDebug